# When using Google forms, how do I get the person's name so I can use it in the confirmation email the user receives after submitting the form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google forms with this field: Firstname

I have managed to set up the confirmation email so that the user receives an email upon submitting the form. However, I want to personalise the email and address it to the person by using their name.

Here is my appscript:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  //response
  //getRespondentEmail()
  var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var subject = "Welcome to MyAPP";
  var textBody = "Welcome to MyAPP";
  var options = { htmlBody: htmlText };

  if(emailTo !== undefined){

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo,subject,textBody,options)}
}
```

here is the email.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <p>Welcome <NAME SHOULD GO HERE> to my APP<p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please tell me how I can add the value from the Firstname field

I tried adding this to the app script but it says error name is not defined:

```
 var name = response.getValuesFromForm().Firstname();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Google Apps Script Form: e.namedValues logs nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28731075/1595451)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit

Answer (score 0):

#### Look at the Form submit event object

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Namely, `namedValues`, which returns an object like this:

```js
{
  'First Name': ['Jane'],
  'Timestamp': ['6/7/2015 20:54:13'],
  'Last Name': ['Doe']
}
```

Note that all the values get returned in an array, even if it's just one value.
To get the information from this object, you can do the following:

```js
let values = e.namedValues
let name = values.Firstname[0] // assigning first item (only item) of Firstname array to name
let email = values.email[0] // assigning first item (only item) of email array to email
```

These properties `Firstname` and `email` may be different depending on how you named them in your form.

It seems you were trying to call the properties as if they were functions - `values.Firstname()` - which will not work, unless you can find that function defined in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms). Or maybe these are functions that are defined elsewhere in your script.

#### References

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Form Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms)