# How to show all answers in confirmation message of current submission in google form using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I used below script but I got message from the previous submission, not the current one.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var response = e.response;
  // Get all the item responses
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  var message = "Thank you for registering for registration. Here are your registration details:\n\n";
  // Iterate through each item response
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    // Append question and answer to the message
    message += question + ": " + answer + "\n";
  }
  // Set confirmation message
  form.setConfirmationMessage(message);
}
```

If I tried to edit the old submission and submited again, then received the current one

Comment: Not possible.⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: @TheMaster - Admittedly I don't use Google Forms very much but I'm wondering why is it impossible?  Since this is a submission why are the current answers unavailable.

Comment: @Cooper IIUC, OP want this: End user submits form -> after submission, they should see the list of their own submitted answers(`question + ": " + answer + "\n"`) in the user interface.  But `onSubmit`  runs independently of the current submission. So, user1 submits form -> script runs -> `setConfirmationMessage` to user1 questions and answers. But user1 can't see that confirmation message. When another user, user2 submits they will be able to see user1's confirmation message, but not their own/ user2's confirmation message.... I think you understand the concept, but not the OP's question here.

Comment: @Cooper To summarize: By the time script finishes, the previous/old confirmation message is already loaded in user1's browser.

Comment: It's too bad they can't delay it like google.script.run waits for the server function to end. It would make more sense to see your own answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script Form: e.namedValues logs nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731075/google-apps-script-form-e-namedvalues-logs-nothing)